# How to manage exceptions correctly in PyQt

Tags: python, exception, pyqt5

I am wondering how to manage multiple exceptions in pyqt

I have a function 'encodeVideo()' that may trigger multiple exceptions.

```
def updateFilename(self):
    try:
        self.model.updateFilename(self.fileName)
    except type_exc.PathIsEmpty as e:
        self.errorDialog.errorTypeChanged(e)
        self.errorDialog.show()

def updateOutput(self):
    try:
        self.model.updateOutput(self.encodeDialog.output)
    except (type_exc.FileAlreadyExists,  type_exc.PathNotExists) as e:
        self.errorDialog.errorTypeChanged(e)
        self.errorDialog.show()

def encodeVideo(self):
    self.updateFilename()
    self.updateOutput()
```

In my case, it is likely to trigger errors both in `updateFilname()` and `updateOutput`. When this happens, a dialog will show up and report both errors. However, I seem to manage the exceptions in a wrong way. For example, when error in `self.updateFilename()` occurs, that doesn't stop my code from continuing the next code `self.updateOutput()`.

Comment: What happens if only one exception occurs, for example in updateFilename? Should the next line run?

Comment: Why should there be a hierarchy between the handling of exceptions? When should an exception be handled with a higher priority? According to understand an exception that is released before has greater hierarchy than others, How long must there be among the exceptions for it to be considered that there is a hierarchy: 1us, 1ms, 1min, etc?

Comment: @Isma the next line will run. I think that I don't manage the exceptions in a right way. Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah, you are right. It sounds an immature idea. I think my real problem is when one exception occurs, it doesn't not stop the code from continuing.

Comment: @yujuezhao If you want the next instruction not to run after the error is released then you must block, that blocking action has several methodologies but in the case of a GUI it has one more requirement: the eventloop should not be blocked, ie block the program cycle without blocking the eventloop and this can be done using the exec_() method of the QMessageBox or QDialog assuming that errorDialog is one of them: change `self.errorDialog.show()` to `self.errorDialog.exec_()`

Comment: @yujuezhao My previous comment assumes that when the exception shows the QMessageBox, stop the execution of the program, then if the user closes the messagebox it will continue with the program and obviously the second exception will be launched (unless the QMessageBox modifies something) opening a new QMessageBox Am I right?

Comment: @eyllanesc Your prediction is correct!  Changing to `self.errorDialog.exec_()` does help to stop reporting both errors at the same time. And a second QDialog would pop out to report the  second error.  I want to quit running the following code in `encodeVideo()` after clicking an OK button of  `self.errorDialog` which reports error in `self.updateFilename()`. Is there any possible way?

Comment: Well that is simple but I do not know if it is what you want, in languages where there are no exceptions (like C) a way to handle so that it does not follow the normal flow of the program is that the functions return a value indicating the state of the execution, for example in your case: `def updateFilename(self):
    try:
        self.model.updateFilename(self.fileName)
        return True
    except type_exc.PathIsEmpty as e:
        self.errorDialog.errorTypeChanged(e)
        self.errorDialog.show()
        return False` `...`

Comment: [cont] `def encodeVideo(self):
    ret = self.updateFilename()
    if ret:
     self.updateOutput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to handle exceptions as a high as possible in your method call stack; this usually means that exceptions are handled in the UI where the first call was made, if inside any of your methods you need to do something if an exception occurs, you should catch and re-throw the exception, here are some examples:

In your code, the first method that is called from the UI is `encodeVideo`, therefore, you want to catch and handle your exceptions there:

```
def updateFilename(self):
    self.model.updateFilename(self.fileName)

def updateOutput(self):
    self.model.updateOutput(self.encodeDialog.output)

def encodeVideo(self):
    try:
        self.updateFilename()
        self.updateOutput()
    except (type_exc.PathIsEmpty, type_exc.FileAlreadyExists,  type_exc.PathNotExists) as e:
        self.errorDialog.errorTypeChanged(e)
        self.errorDialog.show()
```

**Rethrow the exception**

Let's imagine that if the call to `updatedOutput` fails, you want to do something specific, in this case, you can handle the exception in the inner method, but you should rethrow it again so it is handled by the calling method:

```
def updateOutput(self):
    try:
        self.model.updateOutput(self.encodeDialog.output)
    except type_exc.FileAlreadyExists, e:
        print("Do something")
        raise type_exc.FileAlreadyExists(e)

def encodeVideo(self):
    try:
        self.updateFilename()
        self.updateOutput()
    except (type_exc.PathIsEmpty, type_exc.FileAlreadyExists,  type_exc.PathNotExists) as e:
        self.errorDialog.errorTypeChanged(e)
        self.errorDialog.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is basically a exception and error handling problem. And hence if there is error in any block then system takes it as an error handles or exception handles. Thus if first block of code gave error , then  next block contain another handler exception so it is very simple that system treating it as a blocks of errors and exception.